# How to launch Spring Boot app from another Maven module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I got a project which consists of two modules.

- The first one is Spring Boot REST Web Service
- And the second one is the code that should work with this service.

The issue: I need to start Web Service from another module from the code.

Of course, the best option here is to deploy Service to some remote host, but what are the options if I want to launch Service on the local machine?

The first idea was packaging Service module, then copying `jar` to the second module using `maven-dependency-plugin` and launching it as:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar my-rest-service.jar");
```

Can I start Spring Boot app right from another module? Call `Application.main()` method or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `build` and `install` first module into your local maven repository (`.m2` folder by default) as the `jar` library. Then you can use this library in your second module as the maven dependency.

After that you can start your application (second module) as usually `spring-boot` starts - with the `main` method.

---

**Example:**

First module - library:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <url>https://example.com/module1</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <name>module1</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>module1</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Second module - application:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <url>https://example.com/module2</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <name>module2</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!--packaging>war</packaging-->

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>module2</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- com.example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot Maven plugins package our application as executable JARs – such a file can't be used in another project since class files are put into `BOOT-INF/classes`.

In order to share classes with another project, the best approach to take is to create a separate jar containing shared classes, then make it a dependency of all modules that rely on them.

So in your spring boot module, you need to add classifier like:

```xml
...
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and of course, you need to add your spring boot module dependency in your pom where you want to use then you should be able to use `Application.java`.

---

Please check here: [Using a Spring Boot Application as a Dependency](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency).